# Failing To Access Members of Other ViewModel Class in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, class, mvvm

I am working on set of radiobuttons which are dynamicaly generated in my app. I seem to be facing a issue when it comes to access the class members. Here is what I have done till now:

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="Daughter Cards" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,5,20,20" Name="groupBox2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <Grid>                   
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SlotChildren}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="8" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding SlotButtons}" Margin="0,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" GroupName="SlotGroup" Height="15" Width="80" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>                

                <Grid Grid.Column="1">                                                  
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DaughterBoardBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDaughterBoardBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="comboBox5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="158" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DaughterVersionBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDaughterVersionBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="comboBox6" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="158" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding DaughterSerialBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDaughterSerialBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="comboBox7" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="158" />

                        <Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding GetStringCommand}" Content="Get String" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="RefreshDaughterCards" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" />
                        <Button Grid.Row="2" Command="{Binding SetStringCommand}" Content="Set String" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="WriteEEPROMDCBtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="90" />
                        <Label Content="{Binding DaughterStatus}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="DaughterCardLabel" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="170" />
                    </Grid>                                       
                </Grid> 
        </GroupBox>
```

EEPROMViewModel Class:

```
public ObservableCollection<EEPROMSlotViewModel> SlotChildren { get; set; }

public EEPROMViewModel ()
{
        SlotChildren = new ObservableCollection<EEPROMSlotViewModel>();
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "0 : None", ID = 0 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "1 : None", ID = 1 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "2 : None", ID = 2 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "3 : None", ID = 3 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "4 : None", ID = 4 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "5 : None", ID = 5 });
        SlotChildren.Add(new EEPROMSlotViewModel() { ParentVM = this, SlotButtons = "6 : None", ID = 6 });
 }
```

generates 7 radiobuttons with ID related to each.

EEPROMSlotViewModel Class:

```
private string _SlotButtons;
    public string SlotButtons
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private EEPROMViewModel _parentVm;
    public EEPROMViewModel ParentVM
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private int _ID;
    public int ID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

thus whenever I select a radiobutton and click `SETSTRING` button, the following code gets executed:

```
EEPROMSlotViewModel mSlotVM = new EEPROMSlotViewModel();

        string label;
        if (mSlotVM.ID == 0) //Accessing the 1st radiobutton clicked
        {
            label = string.Empty;
            mSlotVM.getShortName(0, label);
            if (label == string.Empty)
            {
                label = "None";
            }

            mSlotVM.SlotButtons = Convert.ToString(0 + ":" + label); // Setting CONTENT of radiobutton selected 
        }
```

Lets say I clicked 1st radio button, ID is supposed to be 0. It calls `getShortName()` method which does the following:

```
ParentVM.SelectedDaughterBoardBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterBoardBoxList[0];
ParentVM.SelectedDaughterVersionBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterVersionBoxList[0];
ParentVM.SelectedDaughterSerialBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterSerialBoxList[0];
shortlabel = "Hello";
```

I am facing few issues here:

- Is `mSlotVM` right way to access other class members/function??
- Once control enters `getShortname()`, it throws the excetion as follows: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at
  `ParentVM.DaughterBoardBoxList[0];`.
- Even if I comment the first 3 statements in getShortName(), When getShortName gets called and once the control comes back, value of
  `label` is "", i should be "hello".

I feel `mSlotVm` this is the reason behind the exception. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you just create a new instance of the `EEPROMSlotViewModel`-Class, youre not accessing any of the RadioButtons ViewModels.
2. It would be helpful if you could show us your `EEPROMViewModel`-Class. I think the problem is, that your `ParentVM.`-Lists are null.
3. To achieve what you want, your `getShortname()`-method has to look like:

   ```
   public void getShortname(int i, ref string shortlabel)
   {
       ParentVM.SelectedDaughterBoardBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterBoardBoxList[0];
       ParentVM.SelectedDaughterVersionBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterVersionBoxList[0];
       ParentVM.SelectedDaughterSerialBoxList = ParentVM.DaughterSerialBoxList[0];
       shortlabel = "Hello";
   }
   ```

EDIT:
Through `EEPROMSlotViewModel mSlotVM = new EEPROMSlotViewModel();` you create a new instance of `EEPROMSlotViewModel`, but youre not getting the checked RadioButtons ViewModel. So at the point were you call `mSlotVM.getShortName(0, label);` mSlotVM has no ParentVM, thats what raises the exception. What you could do is go through your SlotChildren-List and take the EEPROMSlotViewModel whose IsChecked-property is true.

Example:

```
EEPROMSlotViewModel checkedVM;    
string label = string.Empty;
foreach (EEPROMSlotViewModel vm in SlotChildren)
{
    if (vm.IsChecked)
    {
        checkedVM = vm;
    }
    else
    {
        vm.SlotButtons = vm.ID + " : NONE"
    }

} 
checkedVM.getShortName(0, ref label);
if (label == string.Empty)
{
    label = "None";
}
checkedVM.SlotButtons = Convert.ToString(0 + ":" + label); // Setting CONTENT of radiobutton selected
```

Comment: Thanks. Well I have few things to ask: 1. I have already created instance `mSlotVm`, which doesnt seem to work. then which new instance are you talking about? 2. I have updated the `EEPROMViewModel` class for you. I am sure soemthing is wrong here

Comment: 1. If you click the button "Set String" you want to change the string of the checked radiobutton, right? See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to understand what you are trying to say. I would appreciate if you could demonstrate it with a code pls? :)

Comment: Damn this works so nicely :D But lets keep `label = "hello"` and when I click the SetButton, the state(text) of the button goes back to normal state(0: None) when I click another radiobutton. This is the reason Y i had used `If (index == 1)`. How to get rid of this? :(

Comment: F.e. RadioButton1 is checked and you click `Set String` the caption of RB1 changes to "hello". Now you check another RB (e.g. RB2) and click `Set String` again, the caption of RB1 should change back to 0: None and the caption of RB2 should now be "hello", right? Have a look at my edited code.